# Strong induction proof that all $n\geq 1$ counts that$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{4k^2-1} = \frac{n}{2n+1}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, induction

It's probably a very elementary problem, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Proof by means of strong induction that for every natural number $n \geq 1$:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{4k^2-1} = \frac{n}{2n+1}$$

I tried the following:

**Base step:**
Let $n = 1$. In this case:
$$\sum_{i=1}^1 \frac{1}{4-1}  = \frac{1}{2+1} = \frac{1}{3}$$

**Inductive step:**
Fix some $k \geq 1$, and assume that for every $t$ satisfying $1 \leq t \leq k$, the statement is true. We need to prove that:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{4(k+1)^2-1} 
&= \frac{k+1}{2(k+1)+1} \\
\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{4k^2-1} + \frac{1}{4(k+1)^2-1} 
&= \frac{k}{2k+1}+ \frac{1}{4(k+1)^2-1} \\
&= \frac{k}{2k+1} + \frac{1}{4(k^2+2k+1)-1} \\
&= \frac{k}{2k+1} + \frac{1}{4k^2+8k+3} \\
&= \frac{4k^3-8k^2+3k}{(2k+1)(4k^2-8k+3)} + \frac{2k+1}{(2k+1)(4k^2-8k+3)} \\
&= \frac{4k^3-8k^2+5k+1}{(2k+1)(4k^2-8k+3)} \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

And this is pretty much where I get stuck. I was hoping that here at some point I'd be able to factor out the polynomials to get to $\frac{k+1}{2(k+1)+1}$, but I can't figure it out. I probably did something stupid. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the $4k^2+8k+3 =(2k+1)(2k+3) $ which should be in the denominator changed to $4k^3-8k+3$. Proceed rightly and you will get the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: @matthijs _From the third last step to the second last step_, the denominator has changed.

Comment: Good call, that was sloppy of me. I think I should be able to figure it out now! Thanks!